# How to get Jenkinsfile name or the path?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Want to obtain the Jenkinsfile's name or the path of it.

getProtectionDomain and File classes are restricted.

Have the following structure
-pipeline-development
   --Jenkinsfile-development.groovy
-pipeline-test
   --Jenkinsfile-test.groovy

Would like to get the development and test in the jenkinsfile to set environment variable

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to get access to your directory is through `${workspace}` More details about workspace here [enter link description here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project). If you share more details I can probably help for the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Workspace always returns the master's workspace like /mnt/mesos/sandbox/jenkins/workspace/ks_service_embossing_master-5VIGEQGQG44V7BQOBZYMR2KFDIEYIWIRHN2IXN7SU745LREI5A2A

Comment: yes, and you will build your path based on this `${workspace}`. Usually, you know the structure of the git repo so you can write `${workspace}/p1/p2/file`. For the environment variables, you just need to use [parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters).

Comment: But I want to get the p1 and p2 folder names or the file name which is being used to build

Comment: can you infer it from `JOB_NAME`?

Comment: JOB_NAME returns master

Comment: maybe a way around it is to make the jenkinsfile export an environment variable that you can use. At the top of the file you say `def MY_PATH = XX/XX/XX`

Comment: but the path differs. for the jenkinsfile could be either inside the development-pipeline folder or test-pipeline folder and so on.

Comment: Do you have different Jenkinsfile?